# Custom float environment doesn't work with documentclass revtex4-2

Tags: floats, revtex, newfloat

I'm using a custom float environment in one of my documents as described [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Custom_floats). This used to work with `\documentclass{article}`, however, when I change to [`\documentclass{revtex4-2}`](https://journals.aps.org/revtex) it gives me an error which I don't understand. Actually, it's three different errors all referring to the same line (namely the `\end` of the custom float environment):

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.

<to be read again> 
                   \c@float@type 
l.24 \end{program}
                  
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

------------------------------------------------------------

Missing number, treated as zero.

<to be read again> 
                   \endcsname 
l.24 \end{program}
                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

------------------------------------------------------------

Extra \endcsname.

<recently read> \endcsname 
                           
l.24 \end{program}
                  
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.
```

This is an example script to reproduce the error:

```
% \documentclass{article}  % this works
\documentclass{revtex4-2}  % this doesn't work
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}

% From: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Custom_floats
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{program}{hbt}{lop}
\floatname{program}{Program}

\begin{document}

\begin{program}
  \begin{verbatim}

class HelloWorldApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Display the string
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
\end{verbatim}
  \caption{The Hello World! program in Java.}
\end{program}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that `float` is incompatible with `revtex4-2`, which overhauls the definition of the environments `float` expects.

Comment: @egreg Are there any other options for defining custom float environments that are compatible with `revtex4-2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is ridiculously simple. According to [`auguide4-2.pdf`](https://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/auguide/auguide4-2.pdf), all custom floats should be defined outside the preamble

[image]

So that it doesn't throw any errors anymore

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{program}{hbt}{lop}
\floatname{program}{Program}

\begin{program}
  \begin{verbatim}

class HelloWorldApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Display the string
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
\end{verbatim}
  \caption{The Hello World! program in Java.}
\end{program}


\end{document}
```